# Awk multiple pattern matching and formatting the output in to columns from an input file

Tags: awk

I'm gathering stats in a single file on 11 processes and how much memory each one uses at 5 minute intervals.

I'm trying to use awk to multiple pattern match then format the output in to another file so I can import that in to excel to produce a trend analysis.

Each of the lines have 11 unique patterns for example here's the current format:

```
06/09/20 13:30:00 240.73 MB PATTR1
06/09/20 13:30:00 66.28 MB PATTR2
06/09/20 13:30:00 25.26 MB PATTR3
06/09/20 13:30:00 25.12 MB PATTR4
06/09/20 13:30:00 18.43 MB PATTR5
06/09/20 13:30:00 15.82 MB PATTR6
06/09/20 13:30:00 7.69 MB PATTR7
06/09/20 13:30:00 7.34 MB PATTR8
06/09/20 13:30:00 6.08 MB PATTR9
06/09/20 13:30:00 3.86 MB PATTR10
06/09/20 13:30:00 3.84 MB PATTR11
06/09/20 13:35:01 240.88 MB PATTR1
06/09/20 13:35:01 73.31 MB PATTR2
06/09/20 13:35:01 25.26 MB PATTR3
06/09/20 13:35:01 25.12 MB PATTR4
06/09/20 13:35:01 18.43 MB PATTR5
06/09/20 13:35:01 15.82 MB PATTR6
06/09/20 13:35:01 7.69 MB PATTR7
06/09/20 13:35:01 7.34 MB PATTR8
06/09/20 13:35:01 6.08 MB PATTR9
06/09/20 13:35:01 3.86 MB PATTR10
06/09/20 13:35:01 3.84 MB PATTR11
```

I can match all the patterns using awk but unsure how to code awk to get the desired output?

```
awk '/PATTR1/ || /PATTR2/ || /PATTR3/ || /PATTR4/ || /PATTR5/ || /etc../' inputfile
```

What I'm trying to achieve is:

1. Match the 11 unique patterns.
2. Display the data from column 3 on the input file.
3. Format the ouput in 11 column with each column labeled w the respective pattern.

Desired ouput:

```
PATTR1  PATTR2  PATTR3  PATTR4  PATTR5  PATTR6  PATTR7  PATTR8  PATTR9  PATTR10 PATTR11
66.28   240.73  25.12   25.26   18.43   15.82   7.69    7.34    3.86    3.84    6.08
73.31   240.88  25.12   25.26   18.43   15.82   7.69    7.34    3.86    3.84    6.08
80.31   240.96  25.12   25.26   18.43   15.82   7.69    7.34    3.86    3.84    6.08
87.24   241.07  25.12   25.26   18.43   15.82   7.69    7.34    3.86    3.84    6.08
94.05   241.19  25.12   25.26   18.43   15.82   7.69    7.34    3.86    3.84    6.08
100.85  241.31  25.12   25.26   18.43   15.82   7.69    7.34    3.86    3.84    6.08
108     241.44  25.12   25.26   18.43   15.82   7.69    7.34    3.86    3.84    6.08
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Why do you need to match *patterns*, are there other strings in the last column you want to avoid? And are these patterns always sorted as in your example input?

Comment: These are golden gate extract processes which out put to a file the amount of resident set size memory each is using every 5 minutes, querying the /proc/$pid/map file.

Output is in order / linear and the desired output would allow me to import it directly in to excel from a csv file to create a growth chart over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you might be trying to do but I'm not sure because idk why you're trying to match all those "PATTR"s when they appear in every line of input and the expected output you provided doesn't seem to match the sample input you provided and you say you want a CSV to import to Excel but then your expected output doesn't contain any commas:

```
$ awk '
    { hdr=hdr sep $NF; vals=vals sep $3; sep="\t" }
    !(NR%11) { if (NR==11) print hdr; print vals; hdr=vals=sep="" }
' file
PATTR1  PATTR2  PATTR3  PATTR4  PATTR5  PATTR6  PATTR7  PATTR8  PATTR9  PATTR10 PATTR11
240.73  66.28   25.26   25.12   18.43   15.82   7.69    7.34    6.08    3.86    3.84
240.88  73.31   25.26   25.12   18.43   15.82   7.69    7.34    6.08    3.86    3.84
```

If you do want a CSV instead of TSV then just change `sep="\t"` to `sep=","`. If that's not all you need then update your question to provide more truly representative and consistent sample input/output that better captures your requirements.

Comment: Wow @Ed.  Took me lot of time just to understand what is happening here.

Comment: @DigvijayS Really? Any particular part of it that was harder to grasp than the rest?

Comment: why values are reset here `hdr=vals=sep="" `

Comment: If the hdr and vals werent then they'd just keep growing acros the whole file instead of being cleared out after being printed every 11 lines. If sep wasn't then every line after the first block would start with a tab. Try removing that statement (or just parts of it) and you'll see what happens.

Comment: Thank you Ed that works perfectly ! Trying to understand your code now :)

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to ask questions if any part of it isn't clear. I'd also recommend you add `print` statements throughout the script to dump whatever variables you aren't sure of to help you understand it. If you don't know what NR and NF are - see the man page.

Comment: Ed, just thought I would follow up. I noticed that the code assumes the same position for each of the patterns, (These are the goldengate extract process names, I had to omit them). Throughout the every 5 minute capture of their RSS usage the positions will change in terms of greatest amount of RSS used. (I should have been more specific and that's to do with me reverse sorting the RSS usage when I will just leave as is so the patterns are in the same order each time it outputs to the report file).

Comment: Don't expect `goldengate extract process names` means anything to anyone (it certainly doesn't to me) and @oguszismail already asked you if the order was fixed like in your example and you said it was. If the sample input/output in your question isn't truly representative of your real data then fix your example and this time make sure the expected output is exactly the output you expect to get from the posted sample input.